# Can't get OpenLayers 3 to display data from QGIS Server WMS service

Tags: openlayers, qgis-server

I have set up a QGIS server and I can get to the data it spits out via a WMS connection in QGIS desktop.  Now I'm trying to get the same service to display in an OpenLayers 3 map.

Here's the JavaScript I'm trying to use:

```
var map;

function init(){
    map = new ol.Map({
        target:'map',
            renderer:'canvas',
            view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:2966',
            center:[2809414,1031652],
            zoom:5
        })
    });

    var newLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'Lateral', 'FORMAT':'image/png', 
           'VERSION': '1.3.1'}
        })
   });

    map.addLayer(newLayer);
```

Nothing is displayed on the page, and I'm getting a error in the JavaScript console:

```
TypeError: e is undefined ol.js:56
```

If I need to post the html let me know, but there isn't much to it.

Comment: Are you using ol-debug.js or the minified version? You will get more useful error messages from the former.

Comment: It seems you solve it. What was the issue at the end?

Comment: Switching to ol-debug.js did show that it wasn't getting the projection information it needed, your post showed me how to correct that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you do not declare any projection at the beginning of your code, whereas you are using within the view the declaration `projection: 'EPSG:2966',`

You should first declare

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:2966',
  units: 'ft'
});
```

It does not relies on Proj4js, see a [previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/119435/638) to understand it purpose

You can also visit [this official example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html) so see how Proj4js works.

**Edit 1:**

Where does the `'VERSION': '1.3.1'` come? It means that it exists a WMS version 1.3.1 whereas it does not (see the http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms)

You should use `'VERSION': '1.3.0'`. The VERSION parameter manage the x, y axis order.

Comment: Nope, same result, though I'm sure that this solves the next problem I would have had getting this running.  Also, EPSG:2966 is in ft, I assume units: 'ft' is correct, or no?

Comment: Yup, units should be whatever your projection units are?

Comment: Corrected in my answer.

Comment: Your WMS version is wrong, see edit in my answer

Comment: The projection fix got the map tools to load, but not my map.  That's a separate issue that I'll work on and start a new question if needed. Thanks for your help!  I fixed the 1.3.0 as well, 1.3.1 was the version of the Capabilities report QGIS server puts out, the WMS service is still a 1.3.0.

Comment: Final fix:  Needed to reference the map document itself and pick a better zoom level to start with.